# when it is a must to use descendant selectors

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The following code is a part of an html file which utilizes bootstrap. Mainly I want to style `<a>` which has a class `.navbar-brand`. To do so I added another class `.grandchildlink` to `<a>` (don't pay attention to the name). The problem is that it does not work this way.., **the two alternatives were:**

*1.* Using descendant selectors eg. by using the class `.parentbody` of `<body>` and then ( `.parentbody .grandchildlink:hover, .parentbody .grandchildlink:focus{...}`)

*2.* Adding an id attribute to `<a>` say: `grandchildlink_id` and then (`#grandchildlink_id:hover, #grandchildlink_id:focus {...}`)
.., the question is why isn't it working with a one class selector ?

```
.
.
.
    <style type="text/css">
   .grandchildlink:hover, .grandchildlink:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: yellow;
  }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body class="parentbody">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle naviagation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
          <a href="#" class="grandchildlink navbar-brand" >BrandName</a>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul></ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). This is the CSS bootstrap uses.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

That means to overwrite it, you need to use `.navbar-inverse .grandchildlink {}` or something with an equal (as long as your styles come after bootstrap.css) or higher specificity, like you listed in your examples.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
.navbar-inverse .grandchildlink:hover, .navbar-inverse .grandchildlink:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: yellow;
}
</style>
<body class="parentbody">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle naviagation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      <a href="#" class="grandchildlink navbar-brand">BrandName</a>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```